# How can I successfully Build gRPC in C++?

Tags: c++, grpc

I am trying to build gRPC in C++ by following [c++ gRPC installation](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/). My OS is Ubuntu20.4 LTS installed on Raspberry Pi 4.

When I typed this command "make -j"

```
$ cd grpc
$ mkdir -p cmake/build
$ pushd cmake/build
$ cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON \
      -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MY_INSTALL_DIR \
      ../..
$ make -j
```

this error occurs.

```
[  1%] Built target zlibstatic
・
・
[ 97%] Built target mimics_pcre_test
[ 97%] Built target possible_match_test
[ 97%] Built target set_test
[ 97%] Built target regexp_test
[ 97%] Built target search_test
[ 97%] Linking CXX executable bssl
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/bssl.dir/src/tool/transport_common.cc.o: in function `PrintConnectionInfo(bio_st*, ssl_st const*)':
transport_common.cc:(.text+0xd40): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_print_ex'
/usr/bin/ld: transport_common.cc:(.text+0xd74): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_print_ex'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(trust_token.c.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x50): undefined reference to `voprf_exp2_generate_key'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(trust_token.c.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x58): undefined reference to `voprf_exp2_client_key_from_bytes'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(trust_token.c.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x60): undefined reference to `voprf_exp2_issuer_key_from_bytes'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(trust_token.c.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x68): undefined reference to `voprf_exp2_blind'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(trust_token.c.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x70): undefined reference to `voprf_exp2_sign'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(trust_token.c.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x78): undefined reference to `voprf_exp2_unblind'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(trust_token.c.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x80): undefined reference to `voprf_exp2_read'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(x509_vfy.c.o): in function `reject_dns_name_in_common_name':
x509_vfy.c:(.text+0x16dc): undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(x_name.c.o): in function `asn1_string_canon':
x_name.c:(.text+0xe94): undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(v3_crld.c.o): in function `print_distpoint':
v3_crld.c:(.text+0x1304): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_print_ex'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(v3_utl.c.o): in function `do_check_string':
v3_utl.c:(.text+0x288c): undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(algorithm.c.o): in function `x509_digest_sign_algorithm':
algorithm.c:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `x509_rsa_ctx_to_pss'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(algorithm.c.o): in function `x509_digest_verify_init':
algorithm.c:(.text+0x2c4): undefined reference to `x509_rsa_pss_to_ctx'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(v3_alt.c.o): in function `GENERAL_NAME_print':
v3_alt.c:(.text+0x7c4): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_print_ex'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(t_x509.c.o): in function `X509_print_ex':
t_x509.c:(.text+0x404): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_print_ex'
/usr/bin/ld: t_x509.c:(.text+0x52c): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_print_ex'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(t_x509.c.o): in function `X509_signature_print':
t_x509.c:(.text+0xb7c): undefined reference to `x509_print_rsa_pss_params'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/bssl.dir/build.make:339: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/bssl] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4800: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/bssl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show what value the `gRPC_SSL_PROVIDER` variable has? If has `module` than you just init submodules and build with `BoringSSL` ([see](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/.gitmodules#L17-L19) and [see](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/cmake/ssl.cmake#L19-L54)). Another option, you can build with `OpenSSL`, just set `-DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package`.

Comment: I could solve the problem by cleaning up the cloned repository and recloning the grpc. Thank you so much!

Comment: Fix errata: `-DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package` instead of _gPCR_